# Handling data from Firebase with Angular NGRX and displaying in Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli

I have been learning NRGX along with Angular. The app is pretty simple, just a list of employees and by clicking on the employee, it's opening detailed information about him/her.

The problem I have is with NRGX. Before trying to make it work, the service (which is gathering the information from Firebase) was working perfectly.

This code wasn't working for me:

```
this.employeeNRGXList = this.store.select(state => state.employee).pipe()
```

The problem is when I try to pass the data to the table, I receive an error like

> Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

I've tried this, to solve it:

```
this.store.select(state => state.employee).subscribe(data => {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
  this.employeeNGRXList = of(this.dataSource.data);
});
```

If I don't use the pipe async, then nothing appears, but if I use it - I am getting the same error as above.

I have pushed the code to [Github](https://github.com/d3n1el1/nc-final-project/tree/errors), so it would be easier to understand the problem. The code I'm trying to make it work is in TableViewComponent in getEmployeeList(){}.

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, using NgRx; and piping the selector to a component observable. The error message is the same... but not sure how else to get past it.

Comment: You can go to the Github repo I've linked already and see how it's done. I've managed to solve the problem, but I can't remember how I did it right now.